# Recover the OS X Mavericks installer which got deleted automatically after upgrade

Tags: macos, file-recovery, osx-mavericks

I have two MacBooks running Mountain Lion.

I just upgraded one of them to Mavericks. I was hoping to reuse the `/Applications/Install OS X Mavericks.app` that I downloaded for the first Mac on the other one (I have a slow connection with limited data.)

But the file seems to have been deleted automatically once the upgrade was over. It's not even in the Trash.

Is there any easy way to recover this file?

Comment: Have you tried file recovery software?  You got nothing to lose only time and effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you backed up that file somewhere after downloading it from the App Store, no, there is no way to recover the file.

OS X deletes the complete installer after a successful installation.

Answer (score 1):

Apple deletes the installer after installing, just download it again, you can either search the app store for it, or go to the purchases tab and it should be pretty close to the top result.